# How to update views after adding a column to a table

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

In cakephp, after you add a column to a table that's in a model, is there a way to automatically update all the views that are based off of that model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the debug level in core.php to something other than 0, and it should automatically re-cache the database schema and thereby appear in the views (if you are using scaffolding).  If you baked the views, you will have to re-bake them (and potentially lose any changes) or manually add the new column.

Comment: I baked them and had made changes afterwards, so it looks like I'm going the manual route.